# Find multiple strings in avalon Editor

Tags: c#, wpf, avalonedit

I'm using avalon Edit.

I need to find and highlight multiple strings in the editor. Any idea how to achieve that.
I know how to find a single string but I need to find multiple strings and highlight all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using VS 2010? if yes, download SharpDevlop 4.2 code source and take a look at CaretReferencesRenderer.cs file (it can be found under AddIns-> Display Bindings->AvalonEdit.AddIn).